# Problems getting my bibliography working - All citations undefined and "empty bibliography"

Tags: biblatex, texmaker

I've been stressing out for a few hours now trying to get my project to compile. I was originally using Overleaf but my project got too big to compile and so I'm now attempting to compile it using Texmaker.

On Texmaker when trying to quick build, I get warnings that all of my citations are undefined and my bibliography is empty. I am fairly certain Texmaker sees my bibliography file as I've directed which folder to look in.

Here's my main file shortened to the important bits:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes} % Removes babel warning.

\title{\vspace{-5ex}Title}
\author{}
\date{\vspace{-15ex}}

\usepackage[style=ieee,sorting=none,citestyle=numeric,url=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sections/bib.bib}


\section{Project Definition}
\input{sections/definition.tex}

\section{Project Justification}
\input{sections/justification.tex}

\section{Key Literature}
\input{sections/literature.tex}

\section{Project Plan}
\input{sections/plan.tex}

\clearpage

\sloppy
\printbibliography[title=References]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to tell TeXmaker to run Biber on your project, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help with that. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 contains info on what Biber and does and why it is necessary to run it.

Comment: For future questions please note that we don't have your files `sections/bib.bib`, `sections/definition.tex` etc. and thus can not run the code as shown. In general it is better to post code that people can actually compile without additional files (you can test what people will see by compiling the code in an empty directory or in a new, clean project on Overleaf: make sure that the posted code produces the same issue you are asking about). See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864 for more help on good code examples.

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate of our go-to "how do you make my editor run Biber" question for lack of feedback. If it turns out that this doesn't help, please edit your question to make that clearer. In that case please turn your code into a true MWE (see my comment above) and show us  the `.log` and `.blg` files.